# How to compare the inner hash values of following HoH with those of the other list

Tags: perl, hash, hash-of-hashes

```
my %main_hash = ( 
    'hash1' => {
        'key1' => '1-111',
        'key2' => '1-222',
        'key3' => '1-333'
    },  
    'hash2' => {
        'key1' => '2-111',
        'key2' => '2-222',
        'key3' => '2-333'
    }   
);
```

How to compare key values(1-111,1-222,1-333) of inner hashes(hash1) with the corresponding values of following list:

```
$list=   thekey1is : 1-111
         thekey2is : 1-222
         thekey3is : 1-333;
```

and maintain a flag for result of each comparision ?

Comment: the values to be compared are those of hash1 and those after ":" in variable $list .

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this

```
#get all the keys
my @keys = keys %{ $main_hash{hash1} };

#check for each key
for my $key (@keys) {

    if  ($main_hash{hash1}{$key} == $main_hash{hash2}{$key}){
        print "$main_hash{hash1}{$key} and $main_hash{hash2}{$key} Match \n",
    }
    else{
        print "$main_hash{hash1}{$key} and $main_hash{hash2}{$key} Do not match \n",
    }


}
```

Comment: You mean `%main_hash = ( ... )`